# Сохранение отступа строки в RichTextBox, как в IDE. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tab, richtextbox, отступы

Всем привет! Уже кучу времени сижу и думаю над вопросом. Как сделать, так чтобы при создании новой строки(в RichTextBox) в ней было такое же кол-во пробелов и табов, как в предыдущей.

_-пробел

Пример:

```html
<html>
__<head>  //нажимаю enter
__        //получаю это
<html>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в IDE отступы не ставятся где попало, а согласуются со структурой кода. Для этого код анализируется в процессе его набора. Но если по-простому, то можно подсмотреть в предыдущую строку. Что у вас: winforms, wpf?

Comment: Возьмите вместо стандартного какой-нибудь продвинутый компонент. [Fast Colored TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting-2) или [ScintillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).

Comment: @rdorn у меня Winforms